# How Do I Convert an HTML String to a Table?

Tags: javascript, html, string, flask, html-table

I have a table body object stored as a string. I've tried setting an HTML table using javascript to be that string as follows (the {{}} are because I'm using Flask to get the string):

Way 1:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].outerHTML= "{{tbody_string }}";
```

Way 2:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].outerHTML = '<table>' + "{{tbody_string }}" + '</table>'
```

Way 3:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].innerHTML = "{{tbody_string}}";
```

None of these is working. Instead, the table is created and is storing `tbody_string` as actual text content instead of treating it as html. I've used these sort of structures and flask variables with other HTML elements such as `input` and it works fine, but it's not seeming to work with table. Thoughts?

Extra Info:

The string looks like this:

`'<tbody> <tr> <td>Name</td> <td> <input type="text" name="parameters_name" id="name" class="form-control"> </td> </tr> </tbody>'`

The outer quotes are simply shown here to indicate it's a string.

Comment: what is the string like? can you include a sample please?

Comment: I've updated with a sample string

Comment: so what happens with `way 3` ?? does it show any errors?

Comment: Perhaps Flask is your culprit! try way 3 without quotes `"` around {{tbody_string}} or even without `{{` `}}`, if it still doesn't work, try to convert tbody_string to a javascript variable first and then assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinga2 is probably escaping your html when you render it with `{{tbody_string}}`. You can tell it not to do that with `{{tbody_string|safe}}`.

Ultimately you can get rid of your "javascript ways" entirely and just render it directly with Jinja2.

Also...please note that if there is any user editable data in your `tbody_string`, you'll want to take the necessary precautions to avoid creating a security loophole.

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript code for table

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 
 
  var ourTable     = document.createElement("table");
  var ourTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
 
 
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
 
    for (var j = 0; j <2; j++) {
 
 
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell in row "+i+", column "+j);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
 
 
    ourTableBody.appendChild(row);
  }
 
 
  ourTable.appendChild(ourTableBody);
 
  body.appendChild(ourTable);
 
  ourTable.setAttribute("border", "2");
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but the point is that I have a big table with lots of elements and contents and I need to pass it to my website as a string. I don't want my website to then have to try to parse the string into tags and create each tag and append it all correctly --- I should just be able to set `.outerHTML` to the string and have it work. But it doesn't in Jinja in my javascript code (it does if I pull it through a jQuery function instead of passing through Flask/Jinja).

Answer (score 0):

If your **table body object stored as a string** (aka `tbody_string`) is a string that goes something like `tbody_string = "<table><tr><th>table</th></td></table>"`

Way 3 should work fine

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Replace this table</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script lang="javascript">
        const tbody_string = `
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Table</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>this is replaced table</td>
                </tr>
            </table>`;
        document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML = tbody_string;       
    </script>
</html>
```

However, if your tbody_string isn't HTML markup text but something else. 
you'll need to convert it to HTML as text somehow. if it's a DOM element object, the following code should work:

`document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML = table_dom.innerHTML`

Comment: If I ask console to print the string, it prints it as a normal html table (like in your code above). But it doesn't store in the element that way.